# Confusion about dereference operator ("*") in C

Tags: c, arrays, dereference

As far as I know, the derefence operator `*` returns the value stored in the pointer address.  What I'm confused by is the behavior when the operator is used with pointer of an array.  For example,

```
int a[4][2];
```

Then `a` is internally converted to pointer of first element of array of 4 elements of 2 ints.  Then which value does `*a` return?  I'm really confused!

Comment: There is no "pointer to array". An array is not a pointer. "Then `a` is internally converted to pointer of first element of array of 4 elements of 2 ints." is plain wrong!

Comment: @Olaf What do you mean by there is no pointer to array? Doesn't this ( int(*x)[4][2] ) mean that x is a pointer to an array of 4 elements of 2 ints?

Comment: @Olaf Sorry but I still don't get it! Then how should '*a' be interpreted if 'a' is not internally converted to pointer to initial element?

Comment: Really?? Did you consider `a` is called "array" and not "pointer" for a reason? Sorry, but that is a simple logical conclusion (and you gotr the information from tha answers, too). As a programmer, you are **required** to think for yourself in the first place. Please start with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This:

```
int a[4][2];
```

defined `a` an array of 4 elements, each of which is an array of 2 `int` elements.  (A 2-dimensional array is nothing more or less than an array of arrays.)

An array expression is, in most contexts, implicitly converted to a pointer to the array object's initial (zeroth) element. (Note the assumption that there is an array *object*; that has caused some angst, but it's not relevant here.)

The cases where an array expression is *not* converted to a pointer are:

- When it's the operand of `sizeof`;
- When it's the operand of unary `&`; and
- When it's a string literal in an initializer used to initialize an array object.

(Compiler-specific extensions like gcc's `typeof` might create more exceptions.)

So in the expression `*a`, the subexpression `a` (which is of type `int[4][2]`) is implicitly converted to a pointer of type `int(*)[2]` (pointer to array of 2 `int`s).  Applying unary `*` dereferences that pointer, giving us an expression of type `int[2]`.

But we're not *quite* done yet.  `*a` is also an expression of array type, which means that, depending on how it's used, it will *probably* be converted again to a pointer, this time of type `int*`.

If we write `sizeof *a`, the subexpression `a` is converted from `int[4][2]` to `int(*)[2]`, but the subexpression `*a` is *not* converted from `int[2]` to `int*`, so the expression yields the size of the type `int[2]`.

If we write `**a`, the conversion *does* occur. `*a` is of type `int[2]`, which is converted to `int*`; dereferencing that yields an expression of type `int`.

Note that despite the fact that we can legally refer to `**a`, using two pointer dereference operations, there are no pointer *objects*.  `a` is an array object, consisting entirely of 8 `int` objects. The implicit conversions yield pointer *values*.

The implicit array-to-pointer conversion rules are in [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) section 6.3.2.1 paragraph 3. (That paragraph incorrectly gives `_Alignof` as a fourth exception, but `_Alignof` cannot be applied to an expression. The published C11 standard corrected the error.)

Recommended reading: Section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/).

Comment: In the sentence "If we write sizeof *a, the conversion doesn't occur" does the conversion mean from array of 2 ints to pointer to initial element of array of 2 ints? Also I think the next paragraph should be edited as " *a is type int[2], which is converted to int "

Comment: `*a` doesn't have the type `int(*)[2]`; It has the type `int[2]`.

Comment: @jwqwerty: Yes, it's the conversion of `*a` from `int[2]` to `int*` that doesn't occur. I've updated my answer accordingly -- and you're right about the type of `*a`.

Answer (score 9):

The type of `a` is `int[4][2]`, so the type of `*a` (or equivalently `a[0]`) is `int[2]`.

It is *not* the same as `a[0][0]`.  If you do this:

```
int a[4][2];
printf("%d\n",*a);
```

The compiler will tell you this:

> warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’

Since an array (in this case one of type `int [2]`) is being passed to a function, it decays to a pointer to the first element in this context.

If on the other hand you had `**a`, that is equivalent to `a[0][0]` and has type `int`.

Comment: If you're confused by the error message referring to `int *`, its because expresions of array type in any context other than `&` or `sizeof` or related type queries are implicitly converted into pointers.  So `int[2]` becomes `int *`

Comment: @ChrisDodd: What "related type queries" do you mean? An array expression is converted to a pointer unless it is (a) the operand of unary `&`, (b) the operand of `sizeof`, or (c) a string literal in an initializer used to initialize an array (sub)object. Those are the only exceptions. (The N1570 draft of C11 incorrectly lists a fourth, but the `_Alignof` operator cannot be applied to an expression.)

Comment: @KeithThompson: `decltype`, `typeof`, and `alignof` that exist in various extensions, as well as `_Generic`.  Also possibly `offsetof`, though in that case conversion to a pointer would have no effect.

Comment: Actually the first operand of `_Generic` is converted to a pointer if it's of array type. (gcc agrees; clang doesn't, at least as of version 3.7.1.) `offsetof()` can't take an array expression as an argument, so it doesn't apply. Extensions might be another matter.